# Let $X\ge 0$ be a random variable. Show that for any $M\gt 0$ that $M\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X\gt kM)\le E(X)\le M\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X\gt kM)$.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X\ge 0$ be a random variable. Show that for any $M\gt 0$ that
$$M\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X\gt kM)\le E(X)\le M\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X\gt kM).$$

**Attempt**

We know, $E(X)=\int_0^\infty(1-F(x))dx $ and $P(X\gt kM)=1-F(kM)$, where $F$ is distribution function. So by using this I get,  $$M\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1-F(kM)\le \int_0^\infty(1-F(x))dx \le M\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1-F(kM).$$

I was trying to approach like this but can't proceed further. If I am on right track then how to proceed further and if not then how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is this:

Since $\Bbb{P}[X>x]=1-F(x)$, we can write 
\begin{eqnarray}
\Bbb{E}[X] & = & \int_0^\infty \Bbb{P}[X>x]dx\\
& = & \int_0^\infty \Bbb{P}[X/M>x/M]dx\\
& = & M\int_0^\infty \Bbb{P}[X/M>u]du
\end{eqnarray}
with $u=x/M$.
Now, notice that for each $k$, and for all $u\in [k,k+1]$, 
$$
\Bbb{P}[X/M>(k+1)]\leq \Bbb{P}[X/M>u]\leq \Bbb{P}[X/M>k]
$$
hence
$$
\Bbb{P}[X/M>(k+1)]\leq \int_{k}^{k+1}\Bbb{P}[X/M>u]du\leq \Bbb{P}[X/M>k]
$$
hence
$$
\sum_{k}\Bbb{P}[X/M>(k+1)]\leq \sum_{k}\int_{k}^{k+1}\Bbb{P}[X/M>u]du\leq \sum_{k}\Bbb{P}[X/M>k]
$$
which is the same as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X\gt kM)\le \frac{1}{M}E(X)\le \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X\gt kM)$$

Comment: can you please explain last step?

Comment: Yes, sorry. First, $\sum_{k} \Bbb{P}[X/M>(k-1)] = \sum_{k\geq 1} \Bbb{P}[X/M>k] =\sum_{k\geq 1} \Bbb{P}[X>kM] $

Comment: And, second, $\int_0^\infty \Bbb{P}[X/M>u]du = \sum_{k}\int_k^{k+1} \Bbb{P}[X/M>u]du$

Comment: $
\Bbb{P}[X/M>(k-1)]\leq \Bbb{P}[X/M>u]\leq \Bbb{P}[X/M>k]
$, in this step why you have taken $k-1$ and $k$, should not you have taken $k$ and $k+1$.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sorry, it was a typo. I just corrected it.

Comment: But if you are taking the interval $[k-1,k]$ then you should take $k\ge 1$, but then it will create a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46208/discussion-between-nate-river-and-anurag).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

1. Show that $$M \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1_{(kM,\infty)}(X(\omega)) \leq X(\omega) \leq M \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 1_{(kM,\infty)}(X(\omega)) \tag{1}$$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.
2. Integrate $(1)$ with respect to $\mathbb{P}$ and apply the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: By $1_{(kM,\infty)}$, you mean charateristic functionn , right?

Comment: @Human Yes... $1_{(kM,\infty)}(x)=1$ if $x \in (kM,\infty)$ and $0$ otherwise.