# Show $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{n}\text{ exists})=0$

Tags: probability-theory

Given $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ real valued iid. random variables where $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]=\infty$. Consider $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and the event $B:=\{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{n}\text{ exists}\}$ implying also its finiteness. I want to show $$P(B)=0$$

I started by proving that $B$ is a tail event, so I could show $P(B)\in\{0,1\}$. I now somehow have to exclude the value 1, but I am stuck at this.

Comment: It is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1961003/36150) that $\mathbb{P}(B)=1$ cannot happen. Hence $\mathbb{P}(B)=1$.